# Python check if multiple values match search criteria in JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib, json


url = "https://exec85.pythonanywhere.com/static/data_xbox.JSON"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
json_data_xbox = json.loads(response.read())


name_var = "Salah"
rating_var = "96"


if name in json_data_xbox["player"].__str__(): # here I don't know what to write to check if name + rating are matching
    print("matching")

else:
    print("not matching")
```

This is the corresponding JSON file:

```
{"player": [{"name": "Salah", "rating": "96", "rarity": "TOTS", "prices": 5380000}, {"name": "Salah", "rating": "93", "rarity": "FOF PTG", "prices": 956000}]
```

As you see, I have two entries with the same name but different rating and prices.
I would like to check if two variables can be found within one object in my json dictionary to match the right one.
So in this example I want to check if `name_var`and `rating_var` are matching to then get the correct `"prices"` value.

What would I need to write to get that check done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to loop over each dictionary in the response and check that the key values are equal to your variables. Could do something like this:

```
    json_data_xbox = json.loads(
    '{"player": [{"name": "Salah", "rating": "96", "rarity": "TOTS", "prices": 5380000}, {"name": "Salah", "rating": "93", "rarity": "FOF PTG", "prices": 956000}]}')


name = "Salah"
rating_var = "96"

price = ""

for i in json_data_xbox["player"]:
    if i["name"] == name and i["rating"] == rating_var:
        price = i["prices"]

print(price)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! exactly what I was looking for!